# Run yii2 action using windows scheduler

Tags: windows, yii2

I want to make my action in a controller run or executed automatically because I want to send email from my yii2 project automatically. I use windows operating system, so after I search some tutorials, maybe I can use windows scheduler. But, I don't know how to configure my action controller with the windows scheduler? What must I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute actions of controller in Command Line. So, if you can run any command in windows scheduler, then it won't be troublesome.

If you are using Yii2 Advanced Project, then you can see that it consists of two major parts: Backend and Frontend for web access. In addition it contain Console folder, which is used for calling console commands. All you need to do is to create controller in *console/controllers/* directory. Example:

**"MailController.php" in "console/controllers"**

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class MailController extends Controller
{
    public function actionSend() {
        $mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('layouts/main', ['content' => 'blah-blah message'])
            ->setFrom('myweb@site.kz')
            ->setTo('myclient@gmail.com')
            ->setSubject('Оповещение об окончании лицензии');
        if($mail->send()) {
            echo 'Success';
        } else {
            echo 'Fail';
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can run it in console like

```
yii [controller]/[action]
```

In your case, go to you web-application directory, and just call

```
yii main/send
```

P.S sorry for my bad English, and I'm newbie in Stackoverflow

Comment: @RiefSapthana try "php yii main/send"

Comment: So, how can I configure the code with the windows scheduler?

Comment: Did I write the answer above for nothing? You can run commands through windows scheduler, and you can call action codes with cmd too, so what is the problem?

Comment: I want to make the code run automatically. I have tried the code using windows scheduler but there is no email sent to my email. This is the argument in the task/windows scheduler: C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\New\advanced\console\controllers\MailController.php

Comment: C:\xampp\php\php.exe yii main/send

Comment: Firstly, your command is incorrect, secondly I doubt that you has set up your swiftmailer configs. Instead of doing complex tasks at once, start with basics. Open you cmd and execute following:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\[PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT]\yii mail/send
If everything works fine, then write the command to windows scheduler. I suggest you should read documentation

Comment: Is the [PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT] until advanced folder or New folder?

Comment: @yerke I have created a controller and action in Console folder. In my cmd prompt the command "yii controller/action" gave me the output. Now how to execute this command from windows task scheduler. I tried http://htppscode11.blogspot.in/2012/09/taskscheduler-running-yii2-script-using.html but it is not serving the requirement.